# Rectangular hyperbola regression coefficient

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a biology student but ecology chapter bought me to an equation I wasn't able to understand. I know basic hyperbola equation and some terms till class 12

Equation is 
S=C(A^z)
Where z is regression coefficient

And then it was given by the teacher that
Z=S/A
Can anyone tell how???

Answer (score 0):

$$S=C\times A^z\implies \frac S C=A^z\implies \log \left(\frac{S}{C}\right)=z \log(A)\implies z=\frac{\log \left(\frac{S}{C}\right)}{\log (A)}$$

Comment: I got that result.....but I was asking for